# Valor Software Line Chart Table

Tags: angular

This is what i currently want to now. I am fetching from my database data which contains **purchase** and that is what i am binding in my table as **Games[key].purchase**. I want to be able to plot the graph based on the purchase numbers or digits provided in the table. The table shows fine with the purchase values. In my html, i found that the graph is being plotted against the data set in the linechartData in my Games.ts.

i tried this so it could plot against my purchase value but the graph wouldn't plot. How can i assign the values of the purchase to the data in the lineChartData so my linechart will be plotted against my purchase values?

```
public lineChartData:Array<any> = [
            {data: [this.Games], label: 'Series A'},

          ];
```

**Games.html**

```
<div style="display: block;">
    <canvas baseChart width="300" height="150"
                    [datasets]="lineChartData"
                    [labels]="lineChartLabels"
                    [options]="lineChartOptions"
                    [colors]="lineChartColors"
                    [legend]="lineChartLegend"
                    [chartType]="lineChartType"
                    (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
                    (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>

     <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
          <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels">{{label}}</th>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let key of Games | keys" >
            <td *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j=index">{{ Games[key].purchase}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

**Games.ts**

```
Games : Games[] = [];

 public lineChartData:Array<any> = [
        {data: [50, 30, 50], label: 'Series A'},

      ];
      public lineChartLabels:Array<any> = ['January', 'February', 'March'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. Get back to us when you have an actual question.

Comment: @TheHeadRush question updated. :)